# expand wxWrapSizer on secondary direction when adding new items

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a panel that is a list of buttons. The number of buttons changes during runtime (due to user action elsewhere). I use a `wxWrapSizer` to manage these button since I want the height of this panel to remain the same and create a second column of buttons when it runs out of vertical space. The height is managed by the parent sizer based on the other widgets height. This almost works fine but the second column of buttons does not appear until after the window is manually resized.

I have created a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
import wx

start_buttons = 5

class ButtonsPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetSizer(wx.WrapSizer(wx.VERTICAL))
        for i in range(start_buttons):
            self.add_button()

    def add_button(self):
        self.GetSizer().Add(wx.Button(self, label='foo'),
                            wx.SizerFlags().Expand())


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # hardcoded size for sake of example only
        add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add", size=(80, 250))
        add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddButton)

        self.buttons_panel = ButtonsPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(add_button)
        sizer.Add(self.buttons_panel, wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnAddButton(self, evt):
        self.buttons_panel.add_button()
        self.buttons_panel.Layout()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        panel = MyPanel(self)


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Clicking the large "Add" button will add new "foo" buttons but then it stops once it reaches the bottom of the frame. Manually resizing the frame will make the hidden second column appear.

[image: screenshot of the example running]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a `Layout()` of the main panel's sizer rather than the buttons panel sizer.

As the buttons panel's sizer "lives" inside the main panel's sizer, this is the one that needs to be recalculated, as it will recalculate it's children.

```
def OnAddButton(self, evt):
    self.buttons_panel.add_button()
    #self.buttons_panel.Layout()
    self.Layout()
```

Edit:
for more complex setups you may need to note the `parent`or `grandparent` and update from within the buttonpanel i.e.

```
import wx

start_buttons = 5

class ButtonsPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetSizer(wx.WrapSizer(wx.VERTICAL))
        self.parent = parent
        for i in range(start_buttons):
            self.add_button()

    def add_button(self):
        self.GetSizer().Add(wx.Button(self, label='foo'),
                            wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.parent.Layout()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # hardcoded size for sake of example only
        add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add", size=(80, 250))
        add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddButton)

        self.buttons_panel = ButtonsPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(add_button)
        sizer.Add(self.buttons_panel, wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnAddButton(self, evt):
        self.buttons_panel.add_button()
        #self.buttons_panel.Layout()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        panel = MyPanel(self)


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

If it gets truly hellish, you could use `pubsub` to fire a `Layout` in the right place.

Comment: This does fix the minimal example but it doesn't scale. It only works if `MyPanel` is the only child of a `wxFrame` and if that frame does not use a sizer which won't be true other than simple examples like this. Is there a way to signal the frame that it should be call `Layout` because one of it's child/grandchild needs more space?

Comment: The old "minimal" example shoots itself in its minimal foot problem. You could note the ´parent` as `self.parent = parent` and then `self.parent.Layout()`. I'll added a version to the answer.

Comment: Indeed, that's the problem with minimal examples. Still, your edited answer won't solve it because there's more parents to the frame and because the panel of the main frame is on a sizer. But I'm accepting this answer because it does explain the issue and one should be able to get the right answer to their needs from it. For what is worth, I used `self.Layout(); wx.GetTopLevelParent(self).Layout()`. (would also need to call `parent_frame.Fit()` if the window itself needs to be resized)